# Split Development Directory Environment in JDeveloper

Tags: weblogic-10.x, jdeveloper

How do I create a Split Development Directory Environment? I want to use this in JDevloper

Answer (score 0):

[Creating a Split Development Directory Environment](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E15051_01/wls/docs103/programming/splitcreate.html)